# How do I initialize a string variable with a control in Partial class WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a code with eight separate functions. Each having a common string variable `string pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text`. I am writing this line every time I am creating a new function.

I tried declaring it like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string pathFolder = "";
.
.
.
.
.

function One()
{
    pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;
    //Process One
}

function Two()
{
    pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;
    //Process Two
}

function Three()
{
    pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;
    //Process Three
}
```

This works but is it possible to do something like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;
.
.
.
.
.

function One()
{
    //Process One
}

function Two()
{
    //Process Two
}

function Three()
{
    //Process Three
}
```

I am getting an error here

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow.TextBoxPath'

Comment: why not use the `TextBoxPath.Text` directly?

Comment: Use a constructor and set value in that

Comment: Assign pathFolder in the constructor and then set the value for this.

Comment: As hinted by Alex, you should not have this member variable at all. Whenever you need the string later in your code, just get it directly from `TextBoxPath.Text`, e.g. by assigning it to a local variable in a method like `var pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values that you assign as you do (through field initializers), must be known at compile time. `TextBox` is created when the object of class `MainWindow` is created, thus it is run-time.

The error is quite self-explanatory.

What you can do is to assign it in a constructor, after `InitializeComponent` method, where `TextBox` gets initialized. Otherwise you'd get `NullRferenceException`.

Comment: So, if I do this the `string` is always empty as I will not be having any values during `Form_Load()`

Comment: @OmanshuChaurasia Well the way you want to do it, even if it worked, it would mean that your variable would alway be empty, because when you window is initialized, your text box is empty anyway. It's not reference type, `string` is special reference tpye which behaves as value type. So even if text of your text box changes during runtime, the variable will stay empty. The way you have it, using text of textbox directly in you functions is correct and clean way :)